# pandasのdataframeのファイルへの出力

Tags: python, pandas

pandasのデータフレームで下記のようなデータを

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 3))
print(df)

          0         1         2
0  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114
1  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339
```

下記のように出力したいのですが

```
[0, 0] 0.417022
[0, 1] 0.302333
[1, 0] 0.720324
[1, 1] 0.146756
[2, 0] 0.000114
[2, 1] 0.092339
```

良い方法ありますでしょうか？

一応下記の様にすると出力可能となりますが余分なスペースが入ります
より良い方法があれば教えてください

```
df.columns = ["[{0}".format(x) for x in range(df.shape[1])]
df.index = [", {0}]".format(x) for x in range(df.shape[0])]
df.unstack().reset_index().to_csv('test.csv', sep=' ', index=False, header=False, quotechar=' ')
```

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

リスト内の, の後ろのスペースが不要ならば

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 3))
df = df.unstack()
df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda d:'[{},{}]'.format(*d))
df.to_frame().to_csv('out1.csv', header=None, sep=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

でいけます。
リスト内の, の後ろのスペースも必要ならば

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 3))
df = df.unstack().reset_index()
df['level_0'] = '['+df['level_0'].astype(str)+','
df['level_1'] = df['level_1'].astype(str)+']'
df.to_csv('out2.csv', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

でどうでしょうか。（かなり無理やりですが。。）

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 3))

output_list = []
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        print([i, j], round(df.iloc[:, i][j], 6))
        output_list.append(([i, j], df.iloc[:, i][j]))

output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_list)
output_df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

# 読み出し
read_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
for i in range(len(read_df)):
    print(read_df.iloc[i][0], round(read_df.iloc[i][1],6))
```

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？